# What is the better technique to identify and select region in Azure?

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-webapps

I'm trying to create *Web App for Containers* by selecting "Web App For Containers" option in Azure Portal.

When selected region as "Canada Central", got the below error:

> This region has quota of 1 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU.

When selected region as "East US", got the below error:

> The region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU.

Below is my doubt:
Is there anyway to identify what region to select without experiencing these validation errors? Or, is it just a game of selecting one particular region and try our luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid these validation errors and identify the regions with available quota, you can try checking your current subscription quotas.This can be done using the Azure Portal or Azure CLI. Here is a guide to do so:

> In Azure Portal Navigate to the "Subscriptions" page and select your subscription. > Then, under the "Usage + quotas" section, you will find the quotas for various
> resources, including instances.

> If you prefer using CLI here you go,

```
az vm list-usage --subscription SUBSCRIPTION_ID
```

Comment: Hi @Sam, Thank you for your reply. I could able to successfully identify using Azure portal. But, when trying to use CLI command as given above, once again it is forcing me to enter "--location" parameter.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. The command I provided earlier, az vm list-usage, is specific to virtual machines and may not retrieve the quotas for Web App for Containers directly.

Comment: To retrieve the quotas for Web App for Containers, you can use the following command :

`az webapp list-locations --sku <SKU>`


Replace** <SKU>** with the appropriate **SKU** for your Web App for Containers, such as **"B1"** or** "S1"**. This command will list the available locations (regions) along with their quotas for the specified **SKU**.

I hope this update works for you.Sorry for late reply.